# Flush stacked rotated images

Tags: spacing, graphics, rotating

I have a series of images that I would like to line up horizontialy, all scaled to a given height, rotated 90 degrees and *exactly flush* with respect to each other. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}      % Remove all indents
\pagestyle{empty}              % Empty pagestyle

\newcommand{\tallbox}[1]{%
  \resizebox{!}{6cm}{ %
    \includegraphics[angle=90]{#1}  %
  } %
}

\begin{document}%
\tallbox{gen/2354942681964301350.pdf}%
\tallbox{gen/3719368526636490760.pdf}%
\tallbox{gen/4072051681301936821.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to automatically remove the spacing between the graphics. Any combination of negative `\hspace` seems to fail when the height is changed. I've tried changing the lengths:

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\floatsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
```

But none of these seem to change the particular spacing I'm looking for.

Comment: don't use spaces between `}  %` in your definition.

Comment: Note that such transformations can also be easily done with the `adjustbox` package.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Tobi/Herbert just solved it (and I'll accept once I can) but could you show an example with `adjustbox`? I think having that knowledge might be useful for more fine-grained questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three superfluous spaces in the definition of `\tallbox`. Note that the `%` is the right way to omit additional spaces but if Tex reads `…{6cm} %` it sees the argument `{6cm}` followed by a space followed by a comment `%` since TeX reads strictly form left to right the `%` in this case only eats the line break (i.e. a space in the output) but not the preceding space. To omit this space to you must type `%` directly after the last character in a line, as you can see in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}      % Remove all indents
\pagestyle{empty}              % Empty pagestyle

\newcommand{\tallbox}[1]{%
  \resizebox{!}{6cm}{% <----------
    \includegraphics[angle=90]{#1}% <----------
  }% <----------
}

\begin{document}%
\tallbox{gen/2354942681964301350.pdf}%
\tallbox{gen/3719368526636490760.pdf}%
\tallbox{gen/4072051681301936821.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

An other way to omit these spaces is to write the definition in a single line

```
\newcommand{\tallbox}[1]{\resizebox{!}{6cm}{\includegraphics[angle=90]{#1}}
```

I prefer and recommend the first way since it’s much more readable and it’s easier to find matching braces. I nearly always use the “more lines solution” except for simple text replacement, like

```
\newcommand{\TikZ}{Ti\textit{k}Z\xspace}
```

Comment: Thanks Tobi, I didn't even think that those spaces would count, I thought the `%` would eat them up. Is it better practice to put a small function like this on one line or use many `%`?

Comment: @Hooked: See my edit ;-)

Comment: @Hooked: The % "eats" all characters after it, but your spaces were before. In the given solution the % "eats" the end-of-line, which would be otherwise be considered as a space by tex. 
Note that after a commented-out end-of-line, all spaces are ignored until the first non-space. This allows for indentation of the next line.
I think that multiple-line, properly indented code improves readability. You only have to be cautious with those pesky end-of-lines.